# R: Change order of several dataframes in a list depending on mean of a specific column

Tags: r

have several lists containing multiple dataframes. All dataframes have the same two column names but different lengths.

A simple example would be:

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c(1:5), y2 = 3)
d2 <- data.frame(y1 = c(6:13), y2 = 1)
d3 <- data.frame(y1 = c(13:21), y2 = 2)
df_list <- list(d3, d1, d2)
```

Now I´m looking for a solution to calculate the mean of column `y1` in each dataframe in the list and then change the order of the dataframes starting with the one that has the lowest mean of column `y1`.

So far, I was able to calculate the means with:

```
lapply(df_list, function(x) mean(x[,1]))
```

but I can´t figure out how to combine this with `order()`

```
df_list <- df_list[order(lapply(df_list, function(x) mean(x[,1])))]
```

gives me

> "Error in order(lapply(df_list, function(x) mean(x[, 1]))) :
>   unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'"

Thanks for your help!

Comment: change `lapply(...)` to `sapply(...)`

Answer (score 3):

you can do it with the code below, however this does not change your list sequence as the three data frames are already ordered as you specify:

```
df_list=df_list[order(sapply(df_list,function(x) mean(x$y1)))]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You are right, this was a bad example, but it works perfectly, even when I change the order of the example.